# Proof that order is reflexive

Tags: proof-verification, natural-numbers

I am trying to rove Proposition $2.2.12$ in Terence Tao's analysis text. I am a bit stick on part a, which states that for any $a \in \mathbb{N}$, $a \geq a$, a fact I need to prove using only the properties of the natural numbers and their addition. Here is what I have been able to put together so far. I am going to insert parenthetical comments where necessary that hopefully best convey where I am stuck at.

> **Proof.** Let $a \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose toward a contradiction that reflexivity fails and $a < a$. By definition of $<$, this means that $a \leq a$ and $a \neq a$.

This is surely a contradiction. It seems rather obvious that $a = a$, but then am I assuming reflexivity or that "$=$" is an equivalence relation? I don't seem to have an axiom for the natural numbers that allows me to assert equality unless two natural numbers, $n$ and $m$, have the same successor. Then, again, both have the successor which Tao denotes $(a++)$, so perhaps I am free to assert that $a = a$.

I suppose the remainder of the proof with this in mind would take the form:

> Two natural numbers, $n$ and $m$, are equivalent if their successors are equal: 
>   if $(n++) = (m++)$. Clearly, $(a++) = (a++)$, so $a = a$. This contradicts the definition of $<$, as we have shown both that $a = a$ and $a \neq a$. Thus, our supposition fails, and we have $a \geq a$.

How is this? It seems somewhat circular, so I am not sure whether I need to justify that $a = a$, a rather trivial fact.

I wanted to assert something to the effect of $a < a$ implies $a = d + a$ for some positive natural $d$, and since $a + 0 = a$, we have $a + 0 = d + a$, and by cancellation $d = 0$, a contradiction. I believe I am able to assert the latter via Tao's definition of the positive numbers, but the former is an order axiom by itself. It seems that I am only able to assert, via his given foundations, that $d$ is a natural number: it could be zero itself.

I'd greatly appreciate any feedback on this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that equality is defined within the realms of set theory.

Since the natural numbers are usually constructed as [John von Neumann ordinals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers), it is obvious that $a=a$ for every natural number $a$ already from set theory.

Equality has nothing to do with natural numbers in specific (and in particular it is completely independent from Peano arithmetic). For instance, Bourbaki has written a very rigorous book ([N. Bourbaki: Theory of sets](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540225256)) in which $\forall a: a=a$ is proven already within predicate logic.

---

Note that the equal sign is oftentimes used not to denote equality, but also in equations, as a substitute of “corresponds to”, $\dots$. But here we are indeed talking about formal equality.